# Lack of experience in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I was developing a Shoot'em up type of game for my own entertainment in Pygame and I've ran into some doubts midway creatring the basic movements of the player,
both "Dash" and  "Switch" are not working as intended.

```
...

def switch(self):
    if self.offensive_stance() == True:
        self.defensive_stance() == False
    if self.defensive_stance() == True:
        self.offensive_stance() == False
    switch_stance = cycle([self.offensive_stance(), 
    self.defensive_stance()])
    next(switch_stance)
```

#switch() when LSHIFT is pressed is working correctly under the class Player

```
def dash(self, cooldown=200):
    self.last_dash = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    self.cooldown = cooldown

def dash_properties(self):
    now = pygame.ticks.get_ticks()
    if self.last_dash - now >= cooldown:
        self.last_dash= now
        self.rect.x -= self.speedx * 2
        self.rect.y -= self.speedy * 2
...
```

I expect these 2 outcomes for both objects.

Dash (Increment in speed in both x and y axis for 1s followed by a cooldown) - Cannot create it due to lack of experience.

Switch (Cycle between 2 func, Offensive and Defensive) - Cannot create a toggle with LSHIFT properly, defensive_stance only activates while LSHIFT is pressed

Comment: You might have confused `=` (assignment) and `==` (comparison).

Comment: is `self.defensive_stance()` a function ? It seems you want to assign value to this function `if ... : self.defensive_stance() = False`. You can't assign to functions - you have to use variables `if ... : self.defensive_stance = False`

Comment: instead of two variable `self.offensive_stance`, `self.defensive_stance` you could use only one i.e `self.defensive_stance` because `"offensive"` means `"not defensive"` and instead of `if self.offensive_stance == True` you can also check `if not self.defensive_stance == True` which gives `if self.defensive_stance == False`. Or rather you should use `is` instead of `==` for boolean values `if self.defensive_stance is False:`

Comment: How dumb of me to commit that mistake, thanks I'll correct that part and have one less error... (Probably appeared out of despair since this one is bugging me for a while and that was my last attempt), either way one of the problems was the creation of a toggle with key instead of key pressed, I want defensive_stance still active when I take my finger off LSHIFT and change into "offensive" or default once I tap it again, I haven't found anything clear on the library so far.

Comment: i think problem can be in different place - and it can depends on if you use `pygame.event.get()` or `pygame.key.get_pressed()`.

Comment: I use the later, should I change it then?

Comment: with `pygame.key.get_pressed()` you can't get moment when `LSHIFT` change its state from not-pressed to pressed ('False` to `True`). You would have to remeber previous value from `pygame.key.get_pressed()` and compare with current value from `pygame.key.get_pressed()`.  But `pygame.event.get()` gives you `True` only in the moment when LSHIFT change state between not-pressed and pressed ('False` to `True`) or pressed and not-pressed (`True` to 'False`) so you can toggle value in variable when it gives `True` (but not when it gives `False`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal example which uses `LSHIFT` to toggle value in variable `active` and it is used to toggle color (red/green) in rectangle .

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER CASE NAMES)

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 200, 200)
rect.center = screen_rect.center

active = False

# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True

while running:

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

            elif event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
                # toggle
                active = not active

    # --- updates ---

    if active:
        color = GREEN
    else:
        color = RED

    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)        
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(5)

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you were real helpful and had taught me a lot